# Loading new items after showing progressbar with paging library 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-library

I have implemente paging library 3 and it works and shows data , what i need to implement is loading more feature , so when the user scrolls down , it fetch a page 10 items , so basically between loading of new data i want to show a progressbar at the bottom but since it is my first using paging library 3 , i have no clue on how to do that , if someone could i'd appreciate it , thank you

- I tried to show and hide progress bar based on the loadstate of my adapter class but no luck

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
           newsAdapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest { loadingState ->
               if(loadingState.refresh is LoadState.Loading){
                   binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
               }
               if(loadingState.refresh is LoadState.Loading) {
                   binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
               }
               if(loadingState.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading){
                   binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
               }

           }
       }
```

Comment: any solution for that or not yet?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at https://medium.com/@yash786agg/jetpack-paging-3-0-android-bae37a56b92d, I found that we should also observe `append` state, as @dlam wrote.

```
adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->

    if (loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading ||
        loadState.append is LoadState.Loading)
        // Show ProgressBar
    else {
        // Hide ProgressBar

        // If we have an error, show a toast
        val errorState = when {
            loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> loadState.append as LoadState.Error
            loadState.prepend is LoadState.Error ->  loadState.prepend as LoadState.Error
            loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
            else -> null
        }
        errorState?.let {
            Toast.makeText(this, it.error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Searching this for 5 hours :(

Comment: @MehmetGür, nice to hear that you have solved a bug!

Answer (score 0):

`LoadState` for scrolling down is `CombinedLoadStates.append`, not `.refresh` which is when the list gets replaced (initial load / refresh).

Actually if you're interested in `LoadState` aware footer in the style of `ConcatAdapter`, paging has a built-in for this, see: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#load-state-adapter